# Woocommerce new order webhook not firing...how to test?

Tags: php, woocommerce, webhooks

I need to send new order data to a MySQL database on the same server and have setup a Woocommerce webhook but it does not appear to be firing correctly.

I currently use a WooFakePay as a fake payment gateway for testing purposes.

I was able to get it to send header data to requestb.in by manually creating an order but the only data that was received in the raw body was the webhook_id. There is no log on the woocommerce webhook page indicating that it was even sent.

**Questions:**

1. Why aren't the woocommerce webhook logs being generated? (maybe because of WooFakePay?)
2. How do I retrieve/accept the rest of the order data from a webhook ID using PHP?

Comment: did yo get how to test webhooks yet ?

Comment: I still cant make any progress on the woocommerce webhooks.

Comment: Not sure, but I think this can help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371270/how-to-read-data-sent-by-webhooks?noredirect=1#comment48868633_30371270

Comment: I've been testing by setting Delivery URL to a service such as `hookbin.com`.