# How to read data sent by webhooks?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the latest woocommerce plugin, and I have to set a webhook to one of my URL. But I am not able to read it in my $_REQUEST and nor in `$input = file_get_contents("php://input");`.

Comment: do you have a reason to down vote this question?

Comment: Although I wasn't the one to downvote, this is [not a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$webhookContent = "";

$webhook = fopen('php://input' , 'rb');
while (!feof($webhook)) {
    $webhookContent .= fread($webhook, 4096);
}
fclose($webhook);
mail('mail@yourdomain.com', 'test - hook', $webhookContent);
```

This is all it took. It will send all the body to your email