# Catch Http POST Requests from WooCommerce /WebHooks

Tags: php, woocommerce, webhooks

I have a Woocommerce website and a `testwebsite.com/test.php` to catch the request from the webhook.

I would like to display the json data sent by the webhook on the test website.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to anyone who passed by, I found the solution here [How to read data sent by webhooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371270/how-to-read-data-sent-by-webhooks) for anyone who is looking for it

```
$webhookContent = "";

$webhook = fopen('php://input' , 'rb');
while (!feof($webhook)) {
    $webhookContent .= fread($webhook, 4096);
}
fclose($webhook);
mail('mail@yourdomain.com', 'test - hook', $webhookContent);
```